# Check if mail sent is in recipient's inbox/junk in asp.net using C# ?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a software but for that I want to know as if i send an email then how can i check the sent email is in recipient's inbox/ Junk.
I am using AsP.net and c# technology for this
Please reply

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect what is done with the email once it is delivered to the users inbox other than requesting a delivery receipt and a read receipt but the user can opt out of these.

The best way to avoid being marked as spam is to use a trusted third party service such as Campaign Monitor or MailChimp.

Failing that you should make sure that your email has a proper from address set, that you have set up SPF records to allow the sending IP official permission to send email on behalf of the from domain, keep your html to content ratio reasonable and if possible use an email address that your customers have already received an email from before so that there is a higher chance that the address is already in a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't because there are many different email spam solutions out there and they don't send a status back saying whether they delivered the email to the recipient or not. What you can do is send an email with a tracker to see if the receiver opened it.

http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/default.aspx